# telerik doesn't work after change jquery version

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, telerik

I have Project Using Telerik controls
it works fin with jquery 1.8 now we have to  change owe design which require using jquery higher than 1.8 also we will use signalr which require jquery 2.2+
the problem is when we use jquery higher than 1.8 telerik grid stopped working all it's functionality doesn't work any more
giving this errors in console.

telerik.common.min.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'version' of undefined

telerik.textbox.min.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'scripts' of undefined

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'scripts' of undefined
    at telerik.grid.min.js:1
Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).tGrid is not a function

telerik.grid.editing.min.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'scripts' of undefined

I have tried to include Both Jquery 1.8 and 2.2 but it didn't work as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have found a little bit strange solution
i used $.noconflict() function after including both old and new jquery files
like this

```
Jquery=$telerik=$.noConflict();
```

after that i have edited script files of telerik changing Jquery into $telerik
and It Worked Perfectly

Answer (score 0):

You need to import one of these plugins as they provide the interface for tGrid. https://plugins.jquery.com/jqGrid/

Comment: i don't want to replace the telerik grid with another grid i want to make it work with the jquery higher version

Comment: You dont replace it. Its an addon that needs to be imported.

Answer (score 0):

You could try including [jQuery Migrate](https://www.nuget.org/packages/jQuery.Migrate/) in your project - we've had similar issues in the past with Telerik/Kendo, and Migrate seems to have cleared it up.

Hope it helps.

Comment: i have tried this also but not working the problem comes from this line
    @(Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar()
                    .jQuery(true)
        .jQueryValidation(true)
          .Globalization(true))
when i set jquery to false the grid stop working and other design go well
when it's true the design js files gives errors